# What are some good algebraic manipulation workbooks for beginners?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm a high school student that's struggling with manipulating expressions algebraically and I wanted to improve my skills. What workbooks would you recommend for a beginner to practice algebraic manipulation?

Comment: take a promenade https://www.berkeleycitycollege.edu/kpernell/previous-course-resources/precalculus-i-resources/

Comment: Maybe ask your school for help